# Grails How to use filter to do the page login check

Tags: grails, authentication, filter

How can i filter the specify page and controller to do the login check?

And the page is config in the CMS, i think if i want to filter the page, i need to rename the page name in CMS in order to use wildcard character to filter.

Is there any other better way ?

Comment: which plugin is used for login check.

Comment: Use the Spring Security Core Plugin. http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

Answer (score 1):

For example,your application have two controllers named login and customer.
 login controller have two actions. One for to enter login page and another action for authentication.

```
class LoginController {

    def index() {
        render(view:'/loginPage')
    }

    def authenticate() {
        //check username and password is valid. 
        if(valid){ // if valid store the user in session for check user logged in or not in filter or anywhere 
            session.loggedInUser = user
            redirect(controller:'dashboard',action:'home')
        }
        else{ 
            def msg = "Login failed : Invalid Username / Password !"
            render(view:'/loginPage',model:[msg:msg])
        }
    }
```

After login only, we can allow the access to CustomerController.
    For that first create filter and inside the filter copy the following.

```
allExceptLogin(controller:'login', action:'*',invert:true) {
            before = {
                if(!session.loggedInUser) {
                    def msg = "You Should Login"
                        render(view:'/loginPage',model:[msg:msg])
                    return false
                }
            }
}
```

except login controller, every controller's access needs valid user login that is checked in filter.